# Calculate mean of SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

This might be a stupid question but I'm going to ask it anyway because I can't find a way to do it.

I'm trying to find the expectation (and -- if possible -- higher moments) of the solution of the SDE

$$\mathrm d u = -u^3\mathrm d t + u^2 \mathrm d W.$$

Now it is easy to see that

$$\mathbb E u(t) = -\mathbb E \int_0^tu^3(s)\mathrm d s, $$

hence

$$\frac{\mathrm d \mathbb E u(t)}{\mathrm d t} = -\mathbb E u^3(t), $$

but I don't know how to solve this: The third moment of $u$ is in turn related to higher moments and so on ...

Comment: Why do you think the expectation of the stochastic integral is $0$? You don't know whether that integral defines a martingale.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $W$ is Brownian motion, so the Ito integral has zero expectation.

Comment: You should actually also add that the process $u(t)$ is adapted to the filtration of the Brownian motion $W(t)$ in order to make sure that the integral has zero expectation. Otherwise that integral can be whatever.

Comment: @FasEtNefas That is still no guarantee that the stochastic integral is a martingale. You also don't know whether there is a process that satisfies the SDE you have given. So there may be no $u$ to compute the expectation of.

Comment: Even if the adaptation property that @RandomGuy mentioned holds? Also, in that case I am also grateful for hints on how to prove existence (standard results for Lipschitz-continuous coefficients obviously does not hold).

Comment: So my idea for proving existence is that the coefficients are locally Lipschitz, so the solutions exist up to a blowup time. Because of $\mathrm d u^2 = 2\mathrm d u + (\mathrm d u)^2 = -2u^4\mathrm d t + u^2 \mathrm d W_t + u^4 \mathrm d t$, I get (and I'm again assuming the stochastic integral is a martingale) $\mathbb E u(t)^2 = -\mathbb E \int_0^t u^4(s)\mathrm d s$, hence the second moment is decreasing and there can't be a blowup. If that's correct, how do I actually get an expression for $\mathbb E u(t)$ and $\mathbb E u(t)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

We assume that all integrability conditions are satisfied. Since
\begin{align*}
du(t) = -u(t)^3dt + u(t)^2 dW_t,\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we obtain that
\begin{align*}
du(t)^3 &= 3u(t)^2 du(t) + 3u(t)\,d\langle u, u\rangle_t\\
&=3u(t)^4dW_t.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
u(t)^3 = u(0)^3 + \int_0^t 3u(s)^4dW_s.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
E(u(t)^3) = u(0)^3.
\end{align*}
Moreover, from $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
u(t) = u(0) - \int_0^t u(s)^3 ds + \int_0^t u(s)^2 dW_s,
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
E\left(u(t)\right) &= u(0) -\int_0^t E(u(s)^3) ds\\
&=u(0)- u(0)^3t.
\end{align*}

Comment: But now $\mathbb E(u(0)) = 0$ and $\mathbb E(u(1)) = - u(0)$? That doesn't look right...

Comment: @FasEtNefas: See revision. If $u(0)=0$, then $E(u(t))=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this as an answer instead of a comment (but I need to upload a picture). I made a simulation. The slightly thicker blue line is the empiric average of the sample paths shown. To me, it doesn't look like $\mathbb E u(t) = u(0) - u(0)^3t$ (a linear function).[image: Simulation]

Comment: Where did you get this question?

Comment: It's a simplified version of a part of a more complex problem I have.